# how to make sure integer part is unchanged when round a float32 with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

here is my code

```
df = pd.DataFrame([110100.0], dtype=np.float32)
df.round(7)
```

the result is:

110099.992188

what I expect is 110100.0.

**How can I  make sure that the round operation only affect decimal part and the integer part remained unchanged**

for example:
input  =>   expected output

1.0  => 1.0

1.12345678 => 1.1234567

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.modf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html) for extract floats to `fractional` and `integral` parts and round only `fractional` part, last add together:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([110100.0, 1.0, 1.12345678], dtype=np.float32, columns=['col'])

a, b = np.modf(df['col'])
print (b + np.round(a, 7))
0    110100.000000
1         1.000000
2         1.123457
Name: col, dtype: float32
```

Another solution is multiple by number for round, convert to integer and divide:

```
val = 10**7
print (df['col'].mul(val).astype(np.int64).div(val))
0    110100.000000
1         1.000000
2         1.123457
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @scotthuang - I have no another idea, the best wait for another answers...

Comment: thanks. I have another tricks for this, multiply it with 100, round it, then divide 100. but I wan to understand this, because it's a production system, I need to know what's coming.....

Comment: @scotthuang - yes, but instead round is possible convert to integer, check last edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use round function of python and give precision
EG:

```
a = 1.112346789
round(a, 6)
1.112347

round(a, 1)
1.1
```

Comment: for speed and efficiency, I have to use pandas to do calculation. so I try this: df.apply(lambda x:round(x,7)), it don't work.

Comment: Don't use dtype as float32 instead use float or don't specify any datatype.

Comment: I don't have authority to  change data type,